# jQuery - change value

Tags: jquery

I have the following HTML:

```
<div class="right-bar">
 <span class="">£100</span>
</div>

<div class=middle">
 <span class="">£200</span>
</div>
```

The value of the price in the right bar can be changed by selecting an option from a select list.

What I'm looking to do, is to also change the value of the price in the middle div if the value of the right changes.

I have had a look at the `.change()` method in jQuery, but so far I haven't been able to update the second value.

Comment: let's see your jquery code so far!   how are you changing the first value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just add:

```
$("div.middle > span").text($(this).val());
```

to your existing change handler.